# Unexpected behaviour of RegionFunction in 3D Plots

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, regions

This is a continuation of a similar problem I had posted earlier.

I am trying to plot a function defined in a specific parameter space using the `RegionFunction` option in `Plot3D`.

So, this is how I define the region where I want to plot my function

```
Vld[l_, c_] = If[0 < Q3A < 1 && 1 > A > 0 && 1 > B > 0, True,  False]
```

Then, I do

```
A = 1/2; B = 1/2; H = 2/10; G = 1/2;
```

Followed by

```
Plot1 = 
  Plot3D[PU, {L, 00, 1}, {c, 0.0, 1}, 
    AxesLabel -> {"L", "c", "PlatformUtil"},  
    RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Vld[x, y]], 
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> Large]
```

Where `PU` is also a function of the parameters and Q3A.

When I try `Reduce[Vld[L, c] && PU > 2]`

I get `False`

When I look at the plot, I should not see any value above 1, but I see a few spikes in the corner.

[image: PU]

Am I doing something wrong in the way I am using the region function?

Comment: This question is not sufficiently different from your previous question to merit being a separate post. Please update your previous question to include the variation you introduce here.

Comment: Thank you m_goldberg. I have updated my old question.